# . Give an example, with proof, of a function that is not measurable with respect to A.

Tags: measure-theory

Let A be the σ-algebra of subsets of R generated by the intervals (0, 1) and (3, 4).
Give an example, with proof, of a function that is not measurable with respect to
A.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1) Find a set $B$ that is not measurable with respect to the given $\sigma$-algebra

2) Consider the indicator function of $B$. This will be your counter-example.

Comment: Would a non-measurable set be (4,∞)

Comment: How would i go about finding an indicator function

Comment: Indicator function $1_B$ is a function that gets $1$ if the point is in the set $B$ and $0$ otherwise. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: So a dirac measure then?

Comment: not really, read the link.

Comment: So an indicator function would be 5 for example? Which would be a 1 because it's in the set?

Comment: No, the indicator function of a set $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is a function $f$, given a point $x\in \mathbb{R}$ then $f(x)=1$ if $x\in B$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.